# Why is $f_Q(q)$ = 1 in this case?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am looking at this coin sample problem [here](http://www.di.fc.ul.pt/~jpn/r/bugs/bugs_tutorial.html).

A defective coin minting machine produces coins whose probability of Heads is a random variable Q with PDF:

$$f_Q(q) = 3q^2, q \in [0,1]$$

A coin produced by this machine is tossed repeatedly, with successive tosses assumed to be independent. Let A be the event that the first toss of this coin results in Heads...

Say we wish to compute the posterior pdf $f_{Q|A}$ after event $A$.

$$f_{Q|A}(q|A) = \frac{f_Q(q) p(A|q)}{\int_0^1 f_Q(q) p(A|q)~dq}$$

The prior $f_Q(q)$ is the uniform, so $f_Q(q)=1$.  $\leftarrow$ This is what I don't get.

Didn't they just define $f_Q(q) = 3q^2, q \in [0,1]$ already?  Why is it redefined as $1$?  I know the integration of $f_Q(q)$ over [0, 1] is $1$, but $f_Q(q)$ itself is not $1$ from what I can see.  Can someone explain to me?

Comment: It clearly does not match up. Do you have good reason to trust the source from which the question comes?

Comment: Ah, thank you for the criticism of the source.  Gotta think outside of the box sometimes.