# Is my solution for the conditional PDF correct?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Extending from this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3587774/why-is-f-qq-1-in-this-case) which is from this coin sample [problem](http://www.di.fc.ul.pt/~jpn/r/bugs/bugs_tutorial.html).  I found the solution offered problematic when it says $f_Q(q)=1$.

I am absolutely not convinced by the offered reasoning. 
 My solution to that part is:

$$\mathbf P(A\mid Q = q) = q.$$

Thus:

$$\displaystyle f_{Q\mid A}(q\mid A) = \frac{f_Q(q)\cdot\mathbf P(A\mid q)}{\mathbf P(A)} = \frac{3q^2\cdot q}{3/4} = 4q^3.$$

Can someone verify?  Thank you.

Comment: I think your reasoning is correct. The link errs in saying that the prior is uniform, when in fact it has defined a PDF for the random variable $Q$ as being $f_Q(q) = 3q^2$. This is a valid PDF since the integral of this function within the given closed domain $[0, 1]$ yields 1.

Comment: Thank you!  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Agree with JST99. The line from the link
$$
$$
"""The likelihood $p(A \lvert q)$ is given by $P_Q(X \geq q)$ which is the cdf $F_Q(q)=q^3$ """
$$
$$


doesn't make sense either. So the prior is not $f_Q(q) = 1$ but the likelihood is not $p(A \lvert q) = q^3$ either. The likelihood should be $p(A \lvert q) = q$ as the probability of getting heads for a faulty coin is q. So unfortunately the author of the link does two wrongs and gets a right.

Comment: Thanks!  I saw that too.  That part feels really convoluted and illogical.